# VPN gateway software check enforcement as part of access policie

Tags: vpn, corporate-policy, software

Can a VPN gateway enforce policies in form of checking whether a particular software or set of software is installed on the endpoint and based on that allow / deny the remote connection to be established ?

Comment: This comes from a noob and I'm not sure I'm answering your question, but I worked for a company which used Juniper for VPN connections (cannot recall the name) and it required McAfee AV to be installed, otherwise it would not connect.

Comment: @Augusto Do you have any more details on that ?

Comment: Bit of google helped. It look like this is now called **PulseSecure host Checker**, as Juniper sold their networking products a while ago. Check page 14 of https://www-prev.pulsesecure.net/download/techpubs/current/416/pulse-connect-secure/pcs/8.2rx/How_To_Host_Checker.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Augusto I really appreciate your help! Just wondering whether other vendors have that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Trusted Computing Group](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/) (TCG) has defined a set of standards that allow VPN gateways (and other endpoints) to do that in a secure way called [Trusted Network Communications](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/work-groups/trusted-network-communications/) (TNC). Many of them have also been released as RFCs by the [nea](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/nea/documents/) IETF working group and some related ones by the [sacm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/sacm/documents/) working group.

The following image provides an overview of these protocols/interfaces:

[image]

The open source strongSwan IPsec VPN solution [implements these protocols](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/TrustedNetworkConnect) and provides many example use cases, for instance, endpoint assessment (e.g. with [Linux](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IMA) or partially with [Android](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/BYOD)), or creating software inventories together with the [strongTNC](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongTnc) application (and the [swidGenerator](https://github.com/strongswan/swidGenerator) utility). The latter also allows to define policies that are enforced by the VPN gateway (e.g. to only allow restricted VPN access if software updates are missing on a client or other irregularities are found).

There are commercial vendors that implement some of the protocols (e.g. IF-MAP) but they often rely on their own proprietary solutions. For instance, Microsoft provided the [Network Access Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Protection) framework, but that has been removed from the latest releases of their operating systems.